# trying to get perl output json data under a parent

Tags: mysql, perl, json

Here is my code

```
#DATA SOURCE NAME
my $dsn = "dbi:$platform:$database:$host:$port";

#PERL DBI CONNECT
my $connect = DBI->connect($dsn, $user, $pw) || die "Connecttion Error: $DBI::errstr\n";

#PREPARE THE QUERY
my $query = qq(SELECT author, title FROM books);
my $query_handle = $connect->prepare($query);

#EXECUTE THE QUERY
$query_handle->execute();

#LOOP THROUGH RESULTS
while($row = $query_handle->fetchrow_hashref) {
    push @query_output, $row;
}

#DISCONNECT FROM THE DATABASE
$connect->disconnect();

#JSON OUTPUT
print JSON::to_json(\@query_output);
```

and the output as below

```
[{"title":"Android application development for dummies /",
  "author":"Felker, Donn L."},
{"title":"Beginning programming with Java for dummies /",
"author":"Burd, Barry A."}]
```

but i want the output to look like this

```
{"books": 
[{"title":"Android application development for dummies /",
  "author":"Felker, Donn L."},
{"title":"Beginning programming with Java for dummies /",
"author":"Burd, Barry A."}]}
```

to be grouped under "books", how do i do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stick a reference to to `@query_books` inside a hash reference:

```
print JSON::to_json( { books => \@query_books } );
```

See the [Perl References Tutorial](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) for more.